# ¿Cómo juntar números entre paréntesis dentro de una lista de Python?

Tags: python

¿Cómo juntar números entre paréntesis dentro de una lista de Python?

por ejemplo tengo esta lista [('1', '1'), ('3', '3'), ('3', '3'), ('2', '2'), ('2', '2'), ('1', '1'), ('1', '1')]

y quiero transfórmala en esta ['(1,1)', '(3,3)', '(3,3)', '(2,2)', '(2,2)', '(1,1)', '(1,1)']

necesito convertir este tipo de listas en Python por favor me puede responder con código, soy nuevo programando y no entiendo si me responden con algo como usa .join()

Comment: el primer ejemplo es una lista de tuplas que contiene strings y el segundo es una lista de strings

Comment: `[f"({x},{y})" for x,y in tu_lista ]`

Comment: `z = [f'{int(x[0]), int(x[1])}' for x in lista]`.

Comment: Bienvenido, es muy importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, revisar [ask],y no olvides realizar el [tour] del sitio,  saludos.